# Отправка email сообщений c html-тэгами

Tags: php, email

Как передать сообщение с HTML-тегами через PHP переменную на мейл?

```
$sro       = $_POST['sro'];
$name    = $_POST['nameSro'];
$phone   = $_POST['phoneSro'];
$email    = $_POST['mailSro'];
$subject  = "Заявка с сайта";
$message ="<h1>{$sro}</h1>\n" .
           "Имя: {$name}\n".
           "телефон: {$phone}\n".
           " email: {$email}\n".
           " сообщение: {$_POST['message']}";


if (mail("tomail@yandex.ru", $subject, $message)) {
    echo "Отправлено!";
} else echo "Ошибка!";
```

Comment: Вам нужно указать правильныйе `headers`. Конкретно `Content-type:`. Посмотрите вот здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php пример 4.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте вот это:

```
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
```

И поменяйте `mail()` функцию вот на это

```
if (mail("tomail@yandex.ru", $subject, $message, $headers)) {
```

Comment: поправьте ф**ну**кцию на ф**ун**кцию